# CosmosDb change feed: How to set max concurrent calls to 1?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way I can ask change feed to give me only 1 record at a time? I need to debug and getting all the records at once is making it difficult. Can I set something similar to MaxConcurrentCalls like we can do for service bus / queues?

Comment: How did you read the change feed? For [Using the SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#using-the-sdk), you may try to specify [ChangeFeedOptions.MaxItemCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.changefeedoptions.maxitemcount?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_ChangeFeedOptions_MaxItemCount). Please provide more detailed description about your scenario.

Comment: Hi,any updates?Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

As @Bruce mentioned in the comment, you could focus on the `MaxItemCount` option in the `FeedOptions` property during your query.

[MaxItemCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.maxitemcount?view=azure-dotnet) : is the maximum number of items to return per round trip to the server. By setting to -1, you can let the server manage the number of items. Or, you can lower this value to retrieve only a small number of items per round trip.

In addition, you could loop on a finite set of data results for your debugging.

Hope it helps you.